# Some issues with pivot wider and pivot longer in R

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot

Below is the sample data and one manipulation that I have done. I have done something like this before and the code below did the job but now not so. First question, do I need to do the pivot_longer at all? Second, why do I get the NA's

```
 areaname<-c("Clark County","Clark County","Clark County","Clark County","Clark County","Clark County","Clark County","Clark County","Clark County","Clark County","Someplace","Someplace","Someplace","Someplace","Someplace","Someplace","Someplace","Someplace","Someplace","Someplace")
periodyear<-c(2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020)
annualavg<-c(17.56,18.66,19.25,20.35,21.45,22.33,22.44,32.15,33.14,47.555,17.59,18.99,19.33,2.35,88.45,2.33,29.44,36.15,39.14,47.51)

table<-data.frame(areaname,periodyear,annualavg)

table$annualavgr <- round(table$annualavg,digits = 0)

 chart17<-table %>%
 dplyr::select("areaname","periodyear","annualavg","annualavgr")%>%
 ungroup() %>%
 pivot_longer(col = annualavgr, names_to = "measure", values_to = "value") %>%
 group_by(areaname,measure) %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = periodyear, values_from = value)%>%gt()
```

Desired end result (or something close to this)

```
                 2011    2012    2013     2014  and so on.... 
  Clark County    18      19      19       20

                 2011    2012    2013     2014
  Someplace       18      19      19       2
```

Comment: Do you need the average of both 'measure'

Comment: @akrun, No, just the annualavgr. I included this so that it was a duplicate of what I am doing with a larger data set.

Comment: it is because the `col` mentioned was a single one and you don't need `pivot_longer` in that case

Comment: Please check if the last code block is what you wanted

Comment: @akrun, thank you again. the last code section was the desired one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to use both columns in `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
table %>%
  dplyr::select("areaname","periodyear","annualavg","annualavgr")%>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(annualavg, annualavgr),
        names_to = "measure", values_to = "value") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = periodyear, values_from = value)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 12
  areaname     measure    `2011` `2012` `2013` `2014` `2015` `2016` `2017` `2018` `2019` `2020`
  <chr>        <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Clark County annualavg    17.6   18.7   19.2  20.4    21.4  22.3    22.4   32.2   33.1   47.6
2 Clark County annualavgr   18     19     19    20      21    22      22     32     33     48  
3 Someplace    annualavg    17.6   19.0   19.3   2.35   88.4   2.33   29.4   36.2   39.1   47.5
4 Someplace    annualavgr   18     19     19     2      88     2      29     36     39     48
```

---

If we need the average of both 'annual', then

```
table %>%
  dplyr::select("areaname","periodyear","annualavg","annualavgr")%>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(annualavg, annualavgr), 
      names_to = "measure", values_to = "value") %>%   
  pivot_wider(names_from = periodyear, values_from = value) %>% 
  group_by(areaname) %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 11
  areaname     `2011` `2012` `2013` `2014` `2015` `2016` `2017` `2018` `2019` `2020`
  <chr>         <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Clark County   17.8   18.8   19.1  20.2    21.2  22.2    22.2   32.1   33.1   47.8
2 Someplace      17.8   19.0   19.2   2.17   88.2   2.16   29.2   36.1   39.1   47.8
```

---

If we need only a single column 'annualavgr', there is no need to `pivot_longer`, instead just `select` out the 'annualavg'

```
table %>%
   dplyr::select("areaname","periodyear","annualavgr")%>%
   ungroup %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = periodyear, values_from = annualavgr)
# A tibble: 2 x 11
  areaname     `2011` `2012` `2013` `2014` `2015` `2016` `2017` `2018` `2019` `2020`
  <chr>         <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Clark County     18     19     19     20     21     22     22     32     33     48
2 Someplace        18     19     19      2     88      2     29     36     39     48
```